# CSV to html table - client side

Tags: javascript, html-table, import-from-csv

I have a table that I want to append variable data to.  I currently have the data in CSV format, and call the csv to HTML using PHP.  The PHP call `$line_of_text[10]` allows me to access whatever data I want.  However I need to do it client side not server side.

I have been looking into Javascript arrays, and these may or may not be the best idea.  If there is code to parse the data, I would also need the actual code to call it from the HTML page, and put it into the table.

My table is like this:   ( see JS Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/72jQR/2/)

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5"  border="1">    
<tr>
<td>Code</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Description</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Size</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

And After the information from the csv or array or whatever - it looks like this:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5"  border="1">
<tr>
<td>Code</td>
<td>From DATA 12345</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Description</td>
<td>From DATA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Size</td>
<td>500</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

What is the best way to do this client side?

Answer (score 0):

This jQuery plugin should do it for you client-side: http://code.google.com/p/js-tables/

In particular see this page with an example: http://code.google.com/p/js-tables/wiki/Table

Comment: that looks great - Ill do some testing but looks good.  At 1st glance all tables are horizontal rather than vertical but Ill look into it

Comment: At 1st glance all tables are horizontal rather than vertical.  Also it doesnt offer the ability to pull specific data  rows from the csv, and looks like it displays all the csv file, which I dont want to do.  But Ill look into it

Answer (score 0):

There is a CSV to HTML online service at: 
http://okfnlabs.org/blog/2013/12/05/view-csv-with-data-pipes.html

There is also a very simple, lightweight javascript library here you could use: https://github.com/okfn/csv.js (very few dependencies)